# emacs font on MacBook Air

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I just switched to OSX from Ubuntu but I miss the great font that I was using on emacs in Ubuntu. I don't see that font (I am not sure about the name, it is the default font). Is there a way to export that font to OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact answer to your question, but related. I use the Monaco font in Emacs on OSX. If you are running Emacs 24, you can set it up with something like:

`(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Monaco-16")`